# JavaScript catch does not work as expected with an async error throwing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on the error handling with react and firebase user authentication. I am trying to rethrow the error from `signUpWIthEmailAndPassword` to `handleRegisteration` for UI displaying.

```
export const signUpWIthEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
    if (email != null && password != null) {

      auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        throw error;
      })
    } else {
      window.alert("Form is incomplete! Please fill out all fields!");
    }
  }
```

```
const handleRegisteration =  async (e) => {
    console.log("in call back");

    signUpWIthEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .catch((error) => {
      setRegisterationError(error.message);
    });
    
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

However, currently I have the following error in the browser console.
[image]

I have done a lot of research today and none of them seems to work. Please let me now what is the problem here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
export const signUpWIthEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
    if (email != null && password != null) {

      try {
         await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      catch(e) {
        console.log(error.message);
        throw error;
      }
    } else {
      window.alert("Form is incomplete! Please fill out all fields!");
    }
}
```

Use await so your function will wait for `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to be resolved and catch the errors.

Comment: Hi Prime, thank you so much for the answer. The error message can now be successfully displayed. However, would you mind answer two more questions? 1. Why the way I am doing is wrong? I thought we do not need to use `await` if we are using `.catch()` instead of try/catch block. 2. Although, the message is displaying successfully, I am still have the same `uncaught error` in the console. What might be the cause of it? Thank you!

Comment: @zhongman zhang because your code is not waiting for the result of `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. I guess what will happen is `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` will execute **AFTER** `signUpWIthEmailAndPassword` is done

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your code using `await`.

```
export const signUpWIthEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  if (email != null && password != null) {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      throw error;
    }
  } else {
    window.alert('Form is incomplete! Please fill out all fields!');
  }
};
const handleRegisteration = async (e) => {
  console.log('in call back');
  try {
    await signUpWIthEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  } catch (error) {
    setRegisterationError(error.message);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi Prime, thank you so much for the answer. The error message can now be successfully displayed. However, would you mind answer two more questions? 1. Why the way I am doing is wrong? I thought we do not need to use `await` if we are using `.catch()` instead of try/catch block. 2. Although, the message is displaying successfully, I am still have the same `uncaught error` in the console. What might be the cause of it? Thank you!